# TYPO3 language translation bug

Tags: typo3, typoscript, templavoila

I'm having this wierd bug wherein a content is fetched twice

```
    #Page Content
    10 = RECORDS
    10.source.current=1
    10.tables = tt_content
    10.stdWrap.required = 1
    10.wrap =  | 

    #Alternate content is fetched from page 36 if page content not present
    10.stdWrap.ifEmpty.cObject = CONTENT
    10.stdWrap.ifEmpty.cObject {
       table = tt_content
       select.pidInList = 36
    }
```

All these works fine except when I translate the page.
The issue is, **only in my alternate language, this alternate content is fetched twice**.

The translation works fine for normal content. If the user hasn't provided content, a default set has to be fetched. My 'Page Content' is empty in this example, so alternate content is fetched once, whereas in the second language, it is fetched twice.

Btw, this typoscript is written within the XML of the TemplaVoila template.

Any ideas guys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to fix this issue by creating a new content in the alternate language, instead of translating the original content.

When a translated content is called via this method, it is not handled well by TemplaVoila. Then again, maybe it was not designed to do so.

Answer (score 0):

I just came across this issue, I am using the CONTENT module instead of RECORDS (in your example above).

The solution for me was that I was missing the select.languageField line:

```
10 = CONTENT
10.table = tt_content
10 {
    select.where = colPos = 0
    select.pidInList = 47
    select.orderBy = sorting
    select.languageField = sys_language_uid
}
```

Cheers